# How to run bash shell echo in subprocess.run?

Tags: python, subprocess

On a Raspbian Stretch Linux, this `echo` command runs fine in the `bash` shell:

```
$ echo -n -e "Hello World\n"
Hello World
```

Now, I want to execute this same command via Python 3's `subprocess.run`, passed as an array/list; however:

```
$ python3 -c 'import subprocess; result=subprocess.run(["echo", "-n", "-e", r"Hello World\n"], shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE); print(result.stdout)'
b'\n'
```

... I just get a measly linefeed as output ?! Why - and how can I get the full output that I expect?

Note that the Python 3 version here is:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.3
```

Comment: `echo` is a shell builtin, so there's no binary for Python to exec.  You'll have to run something like `bash -c 'echo -n -e 'Hello World\n'"`

Comment: @NikolajŠ.  It would make a `CalledProcessError` if there was no binary found. It should find `/bin/echo`.

Comment: @wim, good point!  I keep forgetting about it =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> shell=True
> ```

You are running the shell.

You are running `sh -c echo -n -e $'Hello World\n'`. I.e. running `subprocess.run(["sh", "-c, "echo", "-n", "-e", r"Hello World\n"])`. (Note: it might not be `sh` and might not be `bash`.)

That results in executing program `sh` with 5 arguments. The interpreter `sh` executes a script `echo` which results in a single empty line. The arguments `-n -e Hello World` are passed as arguments to `sh` and then ignored. See `man sh` or `man bash` section about `-c` option.

Compare in shell `sh -c echo 123` with `sh -c 'echo 123'`. Use `set -x` to debug.

I guess most probably, you intended to:

```
subprocess.run("echo -n -e \"Hello World\\n\"", shell=True...
```

Which would be equal to:

```
subprocess.run(["echo -n -e \"Hello World\\n\""], shell=True...
```

Or you intended to execute the *program* echo (not to be confused with Bash shell *built-in* echo):

```
subprocess.run(["echo", "-n", "-e", "Hello World\\n"])  # implicit shell=False
```

Note that `echo` options are not portable, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html "Application Usage" section. The `-n` `-e` may not work correctly, in particular the executable `echo` (i.e. `/usr/bin/echo` or `/bin/echo`) may parse arguments differently from Bash shell builtin `echo`. You would use `printf` to be portable, but hopefully this is only a showcase example.

Also, you might interested in `subprocess.check_output`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks - I was completely unaware that it is actually `(ba)sh -c` that runs; I always had the impression that with `shell=True`, the arguments in the list run "inside" the shell, somehow; great to be aware of this now.